# What command line options do I use to open VLC, play a single video and then close?

Tags: usb, vlc-media-player, autorun

I'm building an autorun menu in Compact Autorunner to open a series of training videos on a USB stick to send out to sites with unreliable net connections. The idea is that the users will click the button, which will load the portable VLC player on the USB stick, play a specific video and then close. Trying the button, though, loads up everything on the drive into a playlist and plays them all. The launch arguments I'm using are:

```
--fullscreen --play-and-exit <APP_PATH>\Vid_Auto\Auto1.mp4
```

I haven't yet looked up how to avoid the playlist opening, so that's not in the arguments yet.

At the moment everything is stored locally, but it'll eventually all be on the USB stick.

Any idea what I've missed?

Comment: Try adding `vlc:quit` to the command (not `vlc://quit`).

Comment: Cheers - gave it a try, but then it just processes it as a file to play.

Comment: Try adding the option in the parameter file at `%appdata%\vlc\vlcrc`, setting the line `#play-and-exit=0` to be instead `play-and-exit=1` (uncomment and set to `1`).

Comment: I got a solution elsewhere - ended up using `--fullscreen --qt-minimal-view --play-and-exit "<APP_PATH>\Vid_Auto\Auto1.mp4"` Thanks anyway!

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/548915/how-to-run-cvlc-closing-after-the-play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a [solution](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=158664) from Unidan in the Videolan forums; this is the solution I ended up going with:

```
--fullscreen --qt-minimal-view --play-and-exit "<APP_PATH>\Vid_Auto\Auto1.mp4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the command `vlc://quit` to the end of your command line.
This could look like this:

```
cvlc --fullscreen <APP_PATH>\Vid_Auto\Auto1.mp4 vlc://quit
```

As unlikely as it seems - it really works.
The above command opens a VLC window (in fullscreen), plays the video, and then closes the window/program.

Comment: Tried that both with and without the "cvlc" at the start; without it it loads VLC and immediately closes, with it it loads all files on the device into the playlist. Might there be something else getting in the way?

Comment: I am using VLC version 3.0.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. And the output of `cvlc --fullscreen "/media/kubuntu/Data/The Trashmen - Surfin.Bird.mp4" vlc://quit` is "VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari...dummy interface: using the dummy interface module.......plays......idummy demux: command `quit'" and quits. Everything is working in fullscreen. So, unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: That's a thought - I'll try with quotation marks. I'm becoming more and more certain that Compact Autorunner doesn't parse <APP_PATH> into the command line arguments before sending them to VLC, so will try that and report back. :)

Comment: With <APP_PATH> it loads the entire device; without it I get "Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///Vid_Auto/Auto1.mp4'. Check the log for details."

Comment: I have no idea what the environment variable `APP_PATH` would expand to. If you're on Windows, you probably have to include the drive name like `file:///D:/path/to/your/file.mp4` or something like that (I'm not sure about the slashes  - maybe there are 2 or 3 before the drive name).

Comment: <APP_PATH> is a variable the menu system uses to fetch the location, since we can't know for certain what drive letter the USB stick will be loaded as. It's all rather tricky. :-)

Comment: Found a solution - `--fullscreen --qt-minimal-view --play-and-exit "<APP_PATH>\Vid_Auto\Auto1.mp4"` worked a treat. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

[VLC, Tools, Preferences, bottom-right click All under Show settings, Playlist, Play and exit, Save](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=103139). My VLC portable saves/respects that change for good, it appears to change this file: `\VLC\Data\settings\vlc-qt-interface.ini` adding this info:

`headerStateV2=@ByteArray(\0\0\0\xff\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\0\xff\xff\xff\xff\x1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\v\xec\a\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\n\0\0\0\x64\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\x64\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\x64\0\0\0\a\0\0\0\x64\0\0\0\x6\0\0\0\x64\0\0\0\x5\0\0\0\x64\0\0\0\x3\0\0\0\x64\0\0\0\x2\0\0\0\x64\0\0\x2j\0\0\0\v\x1\x1\0\x1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x64\xff\xff\xff\xff\0\0\0\x81\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x5\0\0\0\xc8\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0P\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x2\0\0\0\0\0\0\x1R\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x6\0\0\0\0)`

Thinking you may be able to change the playlist pop-up preference as well.

Comment: Good tip, cheers. :-)